# Zoom- and dragable iframe

Tags: iframe, blazor-webassembly

I'm currently working on a blazor webassembly project, where I have an iframe, which shows a livefeed from a camera. Is it possible to make this iframe, so the user can zoom in on the picture and move the zoomed picture sideways/up/down?

I'm imagining a google maps like frame with both the possibilities of scrolling/dragging to zoom/move. Is this something that can be done?

Thank you

Comment: The question is unclear. An IFRAME displays a different HTML page inside your own. Javascript on your own page can't affect that other page. Google Maps doesn't use IFRAMEs, it uses Javascript code to display maps, layers and zoom them

Comment: Have you checked the camera page's HTML code? How does it display the video? With a `video` element perhaps? You can put that in your own page

Comment: The camera is played as a video element, but I think I have to display it as an iframe element, otherwise it won't show.

Comment: Why? Have you tried using the same video element with the same absolute URL?

Comment: I have, yes. As to why, I can't answer. But assume I manage to display it as a video, will I then be able make it zoom-/dragable? If so, how?